# Asynchronous video streaming in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, video-streaming, android-videoview, mediacontroller

In my android app, i want to stream video from URL. For that i am using `VideoView` control. But it displays starts playing video after loading whole video. I want to perform async video streaming for that. Is async streaming possible with `VideoView` ? I want to display `ProgressBar` until video is loaded. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Here is my code :

```
        video_view_ = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        video_view_.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        video_view_.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        video_view_.requestFocus();
        video_view_.start();
```